# Storing an Inverted index in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, database, database-design, inverted-index

I am working to create a very big inverted index terms. What method would you suggest?

**First**

```
termId - > docId
  a        doc2[locations],doc5[locations],doc12[locations] 
  b        doc5[locations],doc7[locations],doc4[locations]
```

**Second**

```
termId - > docId
  a        doc2[locations]
  a        doc5[locations]
  a        doc12[locations]
  b        doc5[locations]
  b        doc7[locations] 
  b        doc4[locations]
```

**p.s** Lucene is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right table design depends on how you plan on using the data. If you plan on using strings like `"doc2[locations],doc5[locations],doc12[locations]"` *as is* -- without any further postprocessing, then your `First` design is fine.

But if -- as your question tacitly suggests -- that you may at times want to regard `doc2[locations]`, `doc5[locations]`, etc. as separate entities, then you should definitely use your `Second` design.

Here are some use cases which show why the `Second` design is better:

- If you use `First` and ask for all docs with `termID = a` then you
  get back a string like
  `doc2[locations],doc5[locations],doc12[locations]` which you then
  have to split.

  If you use Second, you get each doc as a separate row. No splitting!

  The `Second` structure is more convenient.
- Or, suppose at some point `doc5[locations]` changes and you need to
  update your table. If you use the `First` design, you'd have to use
  some relatively complicated [MySQL string function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to find and replace the substring in all rows that contain it. (Note that MySQL does not come with [regex substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql) built in.)

  If you use the `Second` design, updating is easy:

  ```
  UPDATE table SET docId = "newdoc5[locations]" where docId = "doc5[locations]"
  ```

Comment: What if the terms are in millions, millions of rows?

Comment: I don't think millions of rows should pose any problem on common, modern hardware.